# How to create reverse masks on CALayers

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.ios, calayer, mask

I'll make this as simple as possible.

How do I create reverse masks on `CALayers` in iOS?

I have a red view and an image that is used to mask the red view.
[image]

I use the view's `CALayer`'s mask property to apply the mask, the result is the following.
[image]

However what I desire would be the opposite result, such as
(imagine that the white part here is actually the wood in the background, because I am not very good with image editing software)
[image]

To put in other words: I want the masking image to punch a hole through the view, and not act as an actual masking layer.
Answers in both C# (MonoTouch) or Obj-C are fine either way

Comment: Maybe the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/9944299/78336

Answer (score 4):

Hope it is helpful

Step 1: Create a mask without any alpha channel.

Step 2: Create a invert mask by following method

```
- (UIImage*)createInvertMask:(UIImage *)maskImage withTargetImage:(UIImage *) image {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaNone;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                    CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                    CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef),
                                    nil, 
                                    NO, 
                                    renderingIntent);


    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);

    CGImageRelease(mask);
    CGImageRelease(maskRef);

    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
}
```

Step 3: Set the invert mask to a UIView by following method

```
- (void)maskWithImage:(UIImage*) maskImage TargetView:(UIView*) targetView {
    CALayer *_maskingLayer = [CALayer layer];
    _maskingLayer.frame = targetView.bounds;
    [_maskingLayer setContents:(id)[maskImage CGImage]];
    [targetView.layer setMask:_maskingLayer];
}
```

Finished.

How to call?

```
UIImage* targetImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sky_bg.png"];
UIImage* mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask01.png"];

UIImage* invertMask = [self createInvertMask:mask withTargetImage:targetImage];

[self maskWithImage:invertMask TargetView:targetview];
```

Comment: How do you do this without images? (i.e. reverse a CAGradientLayer)

I created a programmatic CAGradientLayer with the same effect, basically black where I want to pass-through the lower image, fading into white for leaving the underlying view as-is.

Comment: In the inversion function, what is targetImage?

Comment: By the way, kCGImageAlphaNone is not a valid CGBitmapInfo. What's the appropriate constant here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the alpha of your mask, so the "holes" are the transparent pixels. You'll also want to stretch your image to cover the whole red view.

Comment: this is somewhat of a solution, but do you have any example to programatically reverse the alpha of the image and stretch its content size without stretching the actual image?