# How to invert UIImage preserving alpha?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage

On my `UITableViewCell` I set `imageView.image`.  This is a simple black icon on a transparent background.

I want to invert it, when the cell is selected/highlighted, which can be done by setting the cell's `imageView.highlightedImage`.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006328/1971013) but that returns nil, and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9944299/1971013) which turns transparent parts white so you see a white square when cell is selected.

What's the proper way to invert a `UIImage` for this purpose (which works for both normal and retina screens)?  So, I only want to invert the colours; alpha should be preserved.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672517/is-programmatically-inverting-the-colors-of-an-image-possible